# Replacing Strings with numbers in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark and I want to replace names with numbers in a pyspark dataframe column dynamically because I have more than 5,00,000 names in my dataframe. How to proceed?

```
----------
| Name   |
----------
| nameone|
----------
| nametwo|
----------
```

should become

```
--------
| Name |
--------
|   1  |
--------
|   2  |
--------
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and how is it not working?

Comment: there is one function called row_number() you can make use of it here. Go through it once.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have two options I can think of. In case you have only unique names, you can simply apply the [monotonically_increasing_id](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) function. This will create an unique but not consecutive id for each row.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

l = [
('nameone', ),
('nametwo', ),
('nameone', )
]

columns = ['Name']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)
#use Name instead of uniqueId to overwrite the column
df = df.withColumn('uniqueId', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show()
```

Output:

```py
+-------+----------+ 
|   Name|  uniqueId| 
+-------+----------+ 
|nameone|         0| 
|nametwo|8589934592| 
|nameone|8589934593| 
+-------+----------+
```

In case you want to assign the same id to rows which have the same value for `Name`, you have to use a [StringIndexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.StringIndexer):

```py
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="Name", outputCol="StringINdex")
df = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
df.show()
```

Output:

```py
+-------+----------+-----------+ 
|   Name|  uniqueId|StringINdex| 
+-------+----------+-----------+ 
|nameone|         0|        0.0| 
|nametwo|8589934592|        1.0| 
|nameone|8589934593|        0.0| 
+-------+----------+-----------+
```